# Set values around a specific position in a 2D array using Python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

So say I have a 2D array such as:

```
[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

And I want to set all the values 2 levels out around the 3 to a specific number like:

```
[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Note that the 3 could be in any position in the list, I'm using a random generator to get it. So how could I achieve this? Maybe using a for loop?

Comment: is the 3 variable or it is strictly always three?

Comment: and also the rows and columns

Comment: are you usng numpy or is this strict list of lists in base python?

Comment: The 3 is set, but its position can move. And I'm currently not using numpy, but I can if it makes it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carrying on from the comment - I find numpy super useful for slicing like this;

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
])

xs, ys = np.where(arr == 3)
arr[xs[0] - 2: xs[0] + 3, ys[0] - 2: ys[0] + 3] = 1
arr[xs[0], ys[0]] = 3
```

Obviously possible in pure python/list form as well but you will be knee deep in double iteration probably

Comment: Could you explain how this works?

Comment: `where` returns the locations where the array is equal to 3, in your case this is only one place hence use `xs[0]` and `ys[0]` to identify this point. The next line sets the 5x5 grid around the 3 to 1 (including the 3 location) using slice notation https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html (hence my comment about numpy). The last line then just sets the 3 location back to a 3

Comment: Is there a way to then create a border of '2' on the outside?

Comment: `arr[[0, -1]] = 2`
`arr[:, [0, -1]] = 2`

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that what I get back.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure Python approach (albeit rather clumsy):

```
A = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]

for j, a in enumerate(A):
    try:
        i = a.index(3)
        P = A[j-1] if j > 0 else None
        Q = A[j+1] if j < len(a) - 1 else None
        for k in range(max(0, i-2), min(i+3, len(a))):
            if P:
                P[k] = 1
            if Q:
                Q[k] = 1
            a[k] = 1
        a[i] = 3
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
print(A)
```

Comment: Props for trying it but this is what I meant by knee deep in double iteration.

Comment: @Helios I do not disagree with you. I was just trying to implement something without the aid of additional modules. I've abbreviated it slightly

Comment: have tried a version below

Answer (score 1):

pure python

```
A = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]


location = [(i, j) for i, row in enumerate(A) for j, item in enumerate(row) if item == 3][0]
for i, row in enumerate(A):
    for j, item in enumerate(row):
        if (abs(i - location[0]) <= 2) and (abs(j - location[1]) <= 2) and not ((i, j) == location):
            A[i][j] = 1
```